# The & is not allowed for my new password

Tags: php, jquery

I have a window on my site where the visitors can change them password.

The problem is that the & character is never taken :

If I put those two new passwords :

stack&
stack& (the second is the confirmation)

The insertion in the BD is stack (without the &).

This is the js code :

`data: 'nouveau_mdp=' + $('input#champ_nouveau_mdp').val(),`

the alert shwos me "stack&"

In PHP, a var_dump of $_POST gives me :

stack (without the &).

Is & a reserved word for jquery ?

This is my js code :

```
$.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'modification_mdp.php',
                            data: 'nouveau_mdp=' + $('input#champ_nouveau_mdp').val(),
                            dataType: 'text',
                            success: function(reponse) {
                                reponse = $.trim(reponse);
```

Have you an idea to reselove this problem please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post you php code. I'm guessing you are doing some sanitation and that removes the symbols

Comment: How is the `&` character being provided? Note that `&` is reserved in POSTdata and GET querystrings and is used to separate values. It must be escaped first. Are you using the right `<form>` encoding?

Comment: Using js to debug php problem never works. So dont do it

Comment: We'll need to see more of your JavaScript code. Is this part of an AJAX operation? - that looks like part of an associated array.

Comment: I only use <form action="POST"> for the form

Answer (score 2):

Encode the field value

`data: 'nouveau_mdp=' + encodeURI($('input#champ_nouveau_mdp').val()),`

by this way `&` is encoded with the ascii number.

Comment: No, the code above (data: 'nouveau_mdp=' + encodeURI($('input#champ_nouveau_mdp').val()),) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand character is not allowed to pass by Get method or by Post method in PHP. As the usual syntax to access the PHP by GET method is `ines.php?user=username&password=mypassword`,
the '&' character separates the two Variables.

That is why it is does not take '&' from 'Stack&' You may use Javascript to Validate if & is not entered in the text Box. Use JavaScript to encode the varaible... No decoding is required at the PHP end

```
encodeURIComponent("stack&")
```

Comment: You can Endoe the varilabe through javascript before passing it to the PHP Page encodeURIComponent("stack&")

Comment: Thannk you for your reply.  I cannot accept & ?  OK, I'm going to check if the & characters appears and deny the new password.

Comment: The reply of Piyush aggarwal works ! thank you ! encodeURIComponent is working great, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an associative array, which jQuery will encode for you:

```
data: { nouveau_mdp: $('input#champ_nouveau_mdp').val() }
```

You'll need to change the PHP code that receives this value to match (it gets an array rather than a string).

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
data: 'nouveau_mdp=' + $('input#champ_nouveau_mdp').val(),
```

The & character has a special meaning in HTTP. If you had multiple parameters they would be separated by & e.g. nouveau_mdp=mynewpassword&old_mdp=myoldpassword

What you need to do is encode characters such as &, = etc as their hex equivalents i.e. %26 and %3D respectively.

In JavaScript you can do this with the **encodeURI()** function.

Though, as mentioned in the other answer, jQuery also allows you to pass a JSON dictionary of parameters, and it will do the encoding for you.